# TSQL recursive CTE threaded sorting

Tags: t-sql

I have the following table:

```
ID parentID   name

1  0          car1
2  1          tire
3  2          rubber
4  0          car2
5  2          nut
6  3          black
```

To help with testing...

```
CREATE TABLE #TT (ID int
                 ,ParentID int
                 ,Name varchar(25)
                 )

INSERT #TT 
SELECT 1,0,'car1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'tire' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,2,'rubber' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,0,'car2' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,'nut' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,3,'black'
```

I'm trying to create a "threaded" hierarchy, but I want to list the child nodes under their parents like so:

```
ID parentID   name

1  0          car1
2  1          tire
3  2          rubber
6  3          black
5  2          nut
4  0          car2
```

If I use a recursive CTE like this one...

```
;WITH Features
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #TT
    WHERE ParentID = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT F.*
    FROM #TT AS F
        INNER JOIN Features
            ON F.ParentID = Features.ID
)

SELECT *
FROM Features
```

I end up with this...

```
ID parentID   name

1  0          car1
4  0          car2
2  1          tire
3  2          rubber
5  2          nut
6  3          black
```

any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a tree path as you go along, and order it by that

Something like

```
DECLARE @TT TABLE(ID int, ParentID int, Name varchar(25)) 

INSERT @TT  
SELECT 1,0,'car1' UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,1,'tire' UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,2,'rubber' UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,0,'car2' UNION ALL 
SELECT 5,2,'nut' UNION ALL 
SELECT 6,3,'black' 


SELECT  *
FROM    @TT


;WITH Features AS (
        SELECT  *,
                CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX))  + '/' AS TreePath
        FROM    @TT
        WHERE   ParentID = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  tt.*,
                f.TreePath + CAST(tt.ID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/'
        FROM    @TT tt INNER JOIN
                Features f  ON  tt.ParentID = f.ID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Features
ORDER BY TreePath
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an ORDER BY clause such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Features 
ORDER BY parentID
```